# Resource error after updating SDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0

**Install Repository and sync project**

Show in Project Structure dialog

even tried with https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183122#makechanges
but it didn't worked
Please help me out

Comment: Update your Android SDK using SDK manager.

Comment: did that but didn't worked. this error is coming after 6.0 update in sdk

Comment: Did you a resync with gradle?

Comment: yes I even tried with resync

Comment: @SuneetAgrawal Kindly check my answer

Answer (score 0):

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0

Just add this in your <kbd>build.gradle</kbd> Section .

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

**`Update your support repository`** with latest version & **`Clean-Rebuild-RUN`** . again .

### Note

If not working then set

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
```